# Calling Values From A Database into Javascript

Tags: joomla3.0

I have a Joomla 3 site and need to add a calculator from Codeweavers.net. I am using DJ Classifieds and the site is up and running. The calculator is designed to to provide HP or PCP finance. The Javacript fields are below. The info to populate the fields is already in the database.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function loadPlugin() {
codeweavers.main({
pluginContentDivId: 'pluginContent',
vehicle: {
type: 'Car',
identifier: '',
identifierType: 'CAPSHORTCODE',
isNew: false,
cashPrice: '',
mileage: '',
imageUrl: '',
linkBackUrl: '',
registration: {number: ''},
}
});
}
loadPlugin();

</script>
```

The database fields are below:

identifier (field in database is id 27, name capcode )

cashPrice (Price from the item table, name price)

mileage (field in database is id 4, name mileage)

imageUrl (This would be the first image from the vehicle details page)

linkBackUrl (This would be the url for the detail page)

registration (field in database is id 11, name registration)

I am looking for guidance or maybe someone to provide me with a quote to carry out the work? Codeweavers themselves do not provide support for integration.

Thanks

Dave

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with custom codes.
I think it needs spend 3-5 hrs.

I think it will be around 50$

Answer (score 0):

Is that $50 for 3 hours work or the hourly rate?